# Expandable table view bug

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, reload, reloaddata

I have expandable table view cells, everything works, except **animation**. I have one cell with UISwitch, when I tap on it, other cells appear but with some view movements, same thing when I hide these cells when I tap on UISwitch.

I'm using insetGroup Table View and these movements make view  square instead of round.

I want to keep animation, I tried `reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0), with: .fade)` seems like a solution, but it also reloads my header, but I don't want that.

My cellForRowAt func:

```
internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RemindersCell", for: indexPath) as! RemindersCell
    
    cell.switchReminder.isOn = remindersAllowed ? true : false
    cell.switchReminder.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    return cell
}
```

My numberOfRowsInSection func:

```
internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return remindersAllowed ? 5 : 1
}
```

My func for UISwitch:

```
@objc private func switchTapped(sender: UISwitch) {
    
    if !remindersAllowed {
        // Add
        remindersAllowed = true
    } else {
        // Delete
        remindersAllowed = false
    }

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0), with: .none)
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Default `remindersAllowed` is true, when I switch it becomes false and hides cells. I really don't understand what the problem is, any help would be appreciated!

The gif shows this bug when I hide the cells.

[image: Here when I hide cells you can notice]

Comment: Unrelated to the issue but `begin/endUpdates()` has no effect at all when calling `reloadSections`

Comment: What is the issue exactly? What is it about the animated gif you posted that should appear differently?

Comment: @HangarRash Hi, please pay attention to the top left corner when cells are removing

Comment: Oh, I had to zoom in a lot to see a very brief flash of a tiny square corner that only appears on half of the cell removal animations. Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: @HangarRash Yes, this is a problem for me. Because it's conspicuous and not user-friendly. Well, it would be nice if all users were like you and didn't notice it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use activate cell as a tableviewheader

Comment: Thanks for your idea, but I want all cells to be merged, not separated by header. I'm an using insetGrouped table view and that's the problem. In my case, header will be just another view, and I need one big view.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to delete system reload section animation and reload section with `fade` animation:

```
tableView.reloadData()
tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0), with: .fade)
```